# R - Display data by last character

Tags: r

I have read data from a csv to a dataframe - 10 columns and 500 rows. I need to take the second column and display the records only by the last character. There's 500 rows and each record has this format: `"XXXXX-A", "XXXXX-B", "XXXXX-C"` etc. I need to grab the last character (after the dash) and count the occurances of each final character.

I've taken the raw data and put it into `substring`:

```
v1 <- c("XXXXX-A", "XXXXX-B", "XXXXX-A", "XXXXX-C")
substring(v1, nchar(v1)-1)
```

which did return only the last character but I want to do it without manually inputting each piece of data. I imagine some sort of for loop would help but not sure how to structure it.

Answer (score 1):

```
v2 = gsub(".*-.*(.)$", "\\1", v1)
v2
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "C"

table(v2)
#v2
#A B C 
#2 1 1
```

Comment: `and count the occurances of each final character`

Comment: do `table(sub(".*-","",v1))`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `read.table`

```
table(read.table(text = v1, sep = "-")[2])
#A B C
#2 1 1
```

or using `strsplit`

```
table(sapply(strsplit(v1, "-"), `[[`, 2))
#A B C
#2 1 1
```

---

### Sample data

```
v1 <- c("XXXXX-A", "XXXXX-B", "XXXXX-A", "XXXXX-C")
```